# Tag-based syntax highlighting: flask -> python

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

Using the [flask](/questions/tagged/flask) tag should set the default highlighting to `lang-python`.

Comment: Shouldn't questions tagged [tag:flask] be tagged [tag:python], too?